# Configure class and member name casing (lowerCamelCase vs. UpperCamelCase) for "Paste JSON as Classes" in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, camelcasing

Consider this JSON:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "homeAddress": {
        "streetAddress": "123 Main St",
        "city": "Boston",
        "state": "MA",
        "postalCode": "02110"
    },
    "employmentInfo": {
        "employerName": "ABC, Co.",
        "phoneNumber": "617-555-5555"
    }
}
```

In VS I can use the "Paste JSON as Classes" from "Edit > Paste Special".  This is what results:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public Homeaddress homeAddress { get; set; }
    public Employmentinfo employmentInfo { get; set; }
}

public class Homeaddress
{
    public string streetAddress { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
}

public class Employmentinfo
{
    public string employerName { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Notice a couple things: 1.) the class names all have an initial uppercase character and then all lowercase, and 2.) the properties are all lowerCamelCase.

Number 1 doesn't make any sense.  Why would it behave that way, is there an official reason?  Number 2 makes sense, but I'd like to be able to change the behavior so my compiler doesn't complain about naming my properties wrong.

Is there a way to adjust this behavior?

Comment: don't think  you can configure this in VS tbh, albeit this add-on might help you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexanderTatarnikov.JsonFormatter

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the output.  The class HomeAddress is the default casing but the property homeAddress is as it is in the JSON.  Why would the compiler complain?

Comment: @toni -- no the class is "Homeaddress".  The second word is lowercase.  And about your second point: I understand that, but in C# property names are UpperCamelCase (i.e. Pascal Case).  VS complains (based on the way I have it set) when it's not that way, so for large JSON, it's a pain to fix all those or pragma them out.

Comment: I guess I see your point.  And I don't know how to fix.  Although I had no idea this feature existed in VS but it will come in handy for me, more so if someone has an answer for your question.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't come accross a way myself to configure this in Visual Studio.

If you don't mind opening a browser window and copying from there, QuickType is a HUGE time saver

https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp