# Paste JSON as Classes not following C# naming conventions

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Say I had the following json

```
{
    "employees": [{
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }, {
            "firstName": "Anna",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        }, {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Jones "
        }
    ]
}
```

When I use Edit > Paste JSON as Classes the following class gets created:

```
namespace JSONUtils
{

        public class Employee
        {
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Example
        {
            public IList<Employee> employees { get; set; }
        }

}
```

Notice the string `firstName`, this should be `FirstName`. Is there a way of Visual Studio sticking to naming convention rules?

The following site helps do this, but would be great if this was in VS: https://jsonutils.com/

Comment: `Is there a way of Visual Studio sticking to naming convention rules?` No.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54200845/configure-class-and-member-name-casing-lowercamelcase-vs-uppercamelcase-for (I can't mark it as a duplicate since it has no answers - so I'll add an answer here for future searchers). The lack of answer there is because, alas, there is no feature for what you want. So, keep using the website you are using.

Comment: Yeah, you need to use an external site or manually edit the code, unfortunately. You could use a tool like Resharper to do it all at once though.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DangKhuong.JSONtoC or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=typeguard.quicktype-vs may be worth a try if you are using VS 2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way of Visual Studio sticking to naming convention rules?

Alas no. There is no way of customising this (in Visual Studio, **unless you install extra [plugins](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=typeguard.quicktype-vs) / [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DangKhuong.JSONtoC)**).

Your best bet is to keep using https://jsonutils.com or https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp (or one of the plugins / extensions).

Answer (score 3):

It appears this has already been [requested as a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/379864/paste-json-as-classes-add-option-for-c-naming-conv.html) in Nov 2018 and has been queued up for prioritization. Perhaps register your interest on that thread too.

> Your suggestion has been queued up for prioritization. Feature
>   suggestions are prioritized based on the value to our broader
>   developer community and the product roadmap. We may not be able to
>   pursue this one immediately, but we will continue to monitor it up to
>   90 days for community input

This also confirms that the feature doesn't currently exist.

Answer (score -3):

Just select "Pascal Case" setting and select JsonProperty as Property Attribute in jsonuntils website

Comment: yeah im not asking about the site, im asking to do this directly in VisualStudio